# How to fix printing server side output in client side

Tags: java

I have a server code whereby the output is printed half and not all is printed on the client side

The server code is :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int number;
    String temp = null;
    ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1306);
    Socket ss = s1.accept();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
    number = sc.nextInt();
    //temp = number*5;
    switch (number) {
        case 2304: {
            temp = "RESEARCH METHODOLOGY "
            + "\n Madam Cecelia";
            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
            p.println(temp); 
            break;
        }
        case 2404: {
            String temp = "PROJECT MANAGEMENT\n PATRICK Barack";
            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
            p.println(temp);
            break;
        }
        case 2305: {
            String temp = "HUMAN COMPUTER INTERACTION\n Dr. HADULLO";
            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());                  
            p.println(temp);
            break;
        }
    }
```

The client code is as follows which works when client send the unit code and then server responds by the output from the clients request.

```
Scanner sc1= new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    Socket so= new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1306);       
    System.out.println("Enter unit code");
    int number= sc1.nextInt();
    PrintStream p =  new PrintStream(so.getOutputStream());
    p.println(number);
    Scanner sc2= new Scanner(so.getInputStream());
    String temp= sc2.next();
    System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: I have formatted your code for better readability. In the future, please put in the little effort to do this yourself.

Comment: Thanks and will make and an effort to it bu how do i solve the problem? @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score -1):

Try `flush()`ing the PrintStream: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush())

Comment: "void" type not allowed here

Comment: Immediately after "p.println(temp);" add "p.flush();"

Comment: using p.flush()after the p.println(temp); still displays half the input and not the complete output expected